# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_4_0_0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the following stack trace while connecting to a elasticsearch cluster. I have added all the required jars too yet the exception is not resolved.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_4_0_0    
at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:44)  at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:129)   at com.lntinfotech.automation.controller.TestSearch2.main(TestSearch2.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should check:

1. Version of ElasticSearch server is matching with the version of ElasticSearch library (jar).
   Example: If ElasticSearch server version is 2.3.0, using following version of jar will help.

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
>     <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
>     <version>2.3.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Sometimes it may happen, some other libraries (jar) in your project will pull lucene jar (due to implicit dependencies from that jar) and you will unknowingly have two different versions of lucene jar in your project.